# Django Celery IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I want to create a progress bar for my project. I have a class and this class has some functions. Especially, one of them takes a long time (`def download_all`) and this is my main reason for wanting to create a progress bar.

I successfully set up celery, celery-progress, etc. and they work all fine. My problem is this: I want to integrate the progress bar to `download_all` function. I

It gives an error: *IntegrityError at /o.../k...
NOT NULL constraint failed: django_celery_results_taskresult.task_id*

How can I solve it?
**functions.py**

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password, username):
        ...
        self.download_all(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)
        ...

    @shared_task(bind=True, name="my_add")
    def download_all(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)
     ...
     len_scans = len(scans)
     progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
     for s in scans:
         i = 0
         progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, len_scans)
         i += 1
```

**views.py**

```
def setup_wizard(request):
  ...
  functions.Zafiyet(setup.n_username, setup.n_password,
                                          setup.n_url, setup.n_port, setup.db_password,
                                          username=request.user.username)
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/operasyonmerkezi/konfigurasyon

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dashboard',
 'accounts',
 'logs',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_apscheduler',
 'easy_timezones',
 'django_celery_results',
 'celery_progress']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 581, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

During handling of the above exception (TaskResult matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: django_celery_results_taskresult.task_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\dashboard\views.py", line 128, in setup_wizard
    task = (functions.myClass(setup.n_username, setup.n_password,
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\dashboard\functions.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.download_all(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\local.py", line 188, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 389, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\dashboard\functions.py", line 153, in download_all
    progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, len_scans)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery_progress\backend.py", line 46, in set_progress
    self.task.update_state(
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 971, in update_state
    self.backend.store_result(
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\base.py", line 482, in store_result
    self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django_celery_results\backends\database.py", line 66, in _store_result
    self.TaskModel._default_manager.store_result(
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django_celery_results\managers.py", line 46, in _inner
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django_celery_results\managers.py", line 168, in store_result
    obj, created = self.using(using).get_or_create(task_id=task_id,
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 588, in get_or_create
    return self.create(**params), True
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /operasyonmerkezi/konfigurasyon
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: django_celery_results_taskresult.task_id
```

Comment: I have not used _celery_progress_ but Celery Tasks inherit from `Task` — your `myClass` definition **does not**. 

`@shared_task(bind=True, ...` normally means the task instance will be passed in as the first parameter to the call (as _self_). I don't know what that shared_task decorator will do to a class method in the first place — but you have not got a `self` parameter to `download_all`.
 
I don't see how your code as written functions at all — if it does function, I suggest rewriting your question to include a minimally working subset of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check progress of task you have 3 options

1. store current progress as model field in db
2. store as key value in redis db
3. count at runtime by filtering and count element in db with changed status

Frontend can get this result by common REST API or websocket.

example minimum configs for REST API

model.py

```
class MyLongProcess(models.Model):
    active_uuid = models.UUIDField('Active process', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    current_step = models.IntegerField('Current step', default=0)
    total = models.IntegerField('Total', default=0)

    @property
    def percentage_sending(self):
        # or it can be computed by filtering elements processed in celery with complete status
        return int((current_step / total) * 100)
```

views.py

```
def initiate_execute_long_task(request, name):
    process = MyLongProcess.objects.create(active_uuid=uuid.uuid4(), name=name, total=BIG_COUNTED_VALUE)
    async_execute_long_task.delay(process)
    return HttpResponse()


from app.celery import app
@app.task
def async_execute_long_task(process)
    for i in range process.total:
        do_some_staff()
        process.current_step += 1
        process.save()
```

detail.html

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"
  style="width: {{ my_model_object.percentage_sending }}%;"
  aria-valuenow="{{ my_model_object.percentage_sending }}"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{ my_model_object.percentage_sending }}%
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

do not use `self.download_all(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)`

but use it `self.download_all.delay(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)` to run function in celery task

you can use `websocket` and send data for progress to html and update progress bar with `javascript`

each time progress updated progress bar will move

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably do not want to use the `@shared_task` decorator on a method like that.

Your method signature is kind of mangled because of this. The `bind=True` parameter will cause celery to pass the task object into the call, which may produce unexpected results based on your signature.

Demonstration of what I mean by this:

```py
@shared_task(bind=True, name='mytask')
def my_task(the_task, a, b):
    print(the_task)  # a celery Task object
    return a + b
# OR
@shared_task(name='mytask')
def my_task(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Note that these are ordinary functions, not methods in a class.

Now, compound this with the fact that methods on classes implicitly receive `self`, the instance of the class, as the first argument. This is also missing from your signature. It's honestly surprising it executes at all as-written... I would have expected it to fail with a `TypeError` based on the code you provided.

Instead, you should factor out the task to its own function or add the `@staticmethod` decorator over the method first:

```py
class Foo:
    @shared_task(name='mytask')
    @staticmethod
    def bar(a, b):
        ...
```

Winding back your stacktrace, your error comes from an integrity error in the task result table:

> Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: django_celery_results_taskresult.task_id

This happens because your app is, for one reason or another, trying to re-use a task ID and trying to store the result that has already been executed and stored in the DB. This is potentially caused by the issues described above, a bad concurrency model in your app, or an out-of-band change to the database/queue that caused unexpected duplication. You  need to either flush the offending task out of your message queue or remove the offending result from the database, but there may not be guarantees this won't happen again unless you fix the underlying problem with your application code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like came from Django model: "self.model.DoesNotExist".

It is not come from celery, from `Model.objects`.

You'd better check your ORMs.